# What's the difference between use cursor as parameter or in 'where' clause?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a problem when using cursor.

I want know witch way is faster, using as parameter like this:

```
CURSOR c (l_para varchar2) IS
   SELECT ... ...
```

OR just use it as a sample where clause like this:

```
CURSOR c IS
   SELECT xx 
     FROM table 
    WHERE condition = l_para 
     ... ...
```

Witch way i should choose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no functional difference. However, declaring formal cursor parameters makes the code easier to read and hence debug because:

- it is clear that the cursor's result set has a dependency on injected values
- we can see where the injected values are passed, and hence where they come from

Using formal parameters is the sort of convention which supports "self-documenting" code. It's good practice.